# String и сервер

Tags: android, сервер, строки

Сам удивляюсь, что пишу такой вопрос. Всю голову изломал уже, наверное где-то я что-то упустил.

Вот это, знают все:

```
    String str = "какой-то параметр";
```

Но если я делаю это так:

```
    public class БАБАБА {
        String str;

    protected void Любой метод {
    ...какой-то код и потом где-то
    str = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); // - прием string с firebase
```

То str не присваивается значение переданое с сервера, а остаеться null.

Может надо как-то по другому присваивать, каким-то волшебным образом?
Может я где-то по науке что-то пропустил.

Из-за этого делаю такую вот хитрость:

```
    public class БАБАБА {
        String str;
        TextView textView;

    protected void Любой метод {
    ...какой-то код и потом где-то
    str = textView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); // - прием string с firebase
```

Помогите пожалуйста советом.

Comment: Попробуйте привести получаемое значение к типу `String` вот таким методом `str = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue()`

Comment: тут такой момент итересный. я в другой части програмы это делал и все работало. По ходу где-то в моей голове косяк))

Comment: Строке str присваивается null или вылетает NullPointerException? Вот тут: `str = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); // - прием string с firebase`.

Comment: неее, просто null и все

Comment: А `getValue()` какой тип возвращает?

Comment: там string c firebase идет

Comment: Вы уверены, что NPE не вылетает? Проходили дебаггером? Я предполагаю, что в каком-то случае `dataSnapshot.getValue()` возвращает null, а Вы к нему применяете `toString()`! Соответственно, присвоения в `str` не происходит (остается null), вылетает NPE и где-то обрабатывается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39220/discussion-between-tema-bel-and-andrey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должен спасти `String.valueOf(...)`